# How to use thread.join() in Tkinter - Python3?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

When I run this code and click the submit button, GUI screens hangs.
When I interrupt the code, output is displayed on GUI screen, this error is shown.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1033, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1049, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Code -

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import pandas as pd
import gspread
import threading


result = ''
def find_rank(keyword, website, search_query):
 
    # Initialise the required variables
    rank, rank_list = 1, ""
 
    # Base search url of google
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
 
    # Replaces whitespace with "+" in keyword
    keyword = keyword.replace(" ", "+")
 
    # Base url is updated with the keyword to be
    # searched in given number of search results.
    url = url + keyword + "&num=" + str(search_query)
 
    # requests.get(url) returns a response that is saved
    # in a response object called page.
    page = requests.get(url)
 
    # page.text gives us access to the web data in text
    # format, we pass it as an argument to BeautifulSoup
    # along with the html.parser which will create a
    # parsed tree in soup.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
 
    # soup.find_all finds the div, all having the same
    # class "ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi" that is stored
    # in result_div
    result_div = soup.find_all(
        'div', attrs={'class': 'ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi'})
 
    # Iterate result_div and check for the given website
    # inside <a> tag adding the rank to the
    # rank_list if found.
    for div in result_div:
        try:
 
          # Finds <a> tag and checks if the url is present,
          # if present then check with the provided
          # website in main()
            link = div.find("a", href=True)

            if link['href'][7:7+len(website)] == website:
                rank_list += str(rank)+","

            rank += 1
        except:
            pass
    return (rank_list, "Website Missing")[rank_list == ""]
 

def get_rank(keyword, website, search_query):
    rank = find_rank(keyword, website, search_query)
        
    if rank == "Website Missing":
        print(keyword + "  :  "+ rank + "\n")
        exmp.insert(1.0, f"{keyword} :  {rank} \n")
        # result = result + keyword + "  :  "+ rank + "\n"
    else:
        print(keyword + " Rank of Website  :  ", rank[:-1]+ "\n")
        exmp.insert(1.0,f"{keyword}  Rank of Website  :   {rank[:-1]} \n")


gs = gspread.service_account(filename='key.json')

search_query = 200
# for key in df['Keywords']:
#     print(key)
#     get_rank(key, website, search_query)
#     print("\n")




def clicked():

    sheet = gs.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z3oB19yQWVxSmJQHllaV4Xmf_ih5M1slDafvBrQVdXg/edit#gid=0').sheet1
    df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())
    website = "https://www.coden.live/"

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=get_rank, args=(keyword,website, search_query)) for keyword in df['Keywords']]
    for thread in threads:
        
            thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        
            thread.join()


window = Tk()
window.title("Google Rank")
window.geometry('400x400')

websiteVal = StringVar()
gsheetVal = StringVar()
resultVal = StringVar()

a = Label(window ,text = "Webiste", ).grid(row = 0,column = 3, pady=10)
b = Label(window ,text = "Google Sheet",).grid(row = 1,column = 3, pady=10)

a1 = Entry(window, textvariable=websiteVal).grid(row = 0,column = 4,pady=10)
b1 = Entry(window, textvariable=gsheetVal).grid(row = 1,column = 4, pady=10)

exmp = tk.Text(window, width=40, height=10,)
exmp.grid(row=5, column=4, pady=10)



btn = ttk.Button(window ,text="Submit", command=clicked).grid(row=4,column=4, pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Is there anyway I can make this work so that the output is displayed on the GUI without interrupting the code.
What I basically want to do is end the threads successfully.

[image]

Comment: Don't call the `join()` because it will block tkinter mainloop from handling pending events and updates until the thread ends.

Comment: @acw1668 how can I make this work in background without blocking the UI

Comment: Just what I said, don't call `join()`.